# Programmatically update resources inside of APK

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically update the resources (more specifically icons and strings) within an APK on the device?  I know I can get the APK path from an app's ApplicationInfo object.  I also know that APKs are simply zip files and I can use ZipFie (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile) to read/modify its contents so I feel like this should be possible.

One idea I had on doing this would be to build apktool (https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and include this in my app.  I could then decompile the resources, make my modifications, re-compile and use ZipFile to include it.  This seems quite heavy though to do on an Android device.  Is there any more efficient approaches?

Comment: apk is not a simple zip file, it contains a digital signature that protects integrity. If you change the contents you must resign it. I would suggest to store non-static data in a file in the internal storage or in a database instead.

Comment: The APK wouldn't be installed so the signature part isn't a concern.  Thanks for raising the point though.

Comment: A better option would be to use a storage directory that you extract the "original" files from (from the APK) then update the files in the storage directory. Error checking would be required during the update.

Comment: I was thinking of this approach but it seems too expensive to decompile, then make changes, and then re-compile on a device.  If there is no other approach, then I guess I can try it and see what the performance is like though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hot fix framework ,like Tencent's [Tinker](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker) and Alibaba's Sophix(here is a [Chinese doc](https://blog.csdn.net/lin_t_s/article/details/78850483))

Those hot fix framework can update your java code,so file and string drawable resource dynamically.